# Git loses connection during push

Tags: git, github, connection

So I'm just getting started with GIT, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to publish my local repo on Github, but when I do this I seem to keep losing connection.

I can check the origin using `git remote -v` giving me 
`origin  git@github.com:Yorgv/yorgv.be.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Yorgv/yorgv.be.git (push)`, so I think I've set up the ssh-key correctly.

I already tried increasing buffer size by using `git config --global http.postBuffer 200000000`, but to no avail.

The weird thing is that often when I try to push, my wifi-connection is lost, and I have to reconnect.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 39, done.
Counting objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Connection reset by 140.82.118.4 port 22
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipes
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm pretty new to all this and I hope someone will be able to help me out of this mess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wifi connection goes down when pushing? That is probably why you see that message.... and the wifi connection should not go down when pushing at all. You would need to check your wireless AP, your wifi network drivers, etc... you would need to check just about anything related to the wireless network but git.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer @eftshift0, but the problem has resolved itself. After hours of trying and troubleshooting and restarting my pc, I gave up. A few hours later I try again and it just works.

Comment: If the problem can be reproduced, you could try `strace git push origin master` to print logs in details which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, the problem has seemed to resolve itself. I gave up after hours of troubleshooting and restarting my pc and trying all different things, and when I returned later to try once more it just works.
I still have no idea what caused this behaviour but I'll give an update when I know more...